# IIS w3c logfile order of the different fields?

Tags: iis, logging, format

I have a W3C logfile of IIS access log.
I can't find out what the numbers mean:

```
2012-10-25 19:18:00 10.234.150.43 GET /status.aspx - 8080 - 10.0.0.1 - 200 0 0 0
```

Of course some of the fields are clear, but what do the three zero's at the end stand for?

I didn't customize the logging in any way...

Comment: I'm stupid, didn't look at the top of the file, there's a header there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header of the log file should contain a header which contains the fieldnames:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
```

Comment: I don't have any headers in my log files, unfortunately. I can't check the settings without disabling logging, either, which seems crazy.

Comment: I gave up and disabled logging, but the Select Fields button is still grey, so I guess I can't look at the settings anyway. Argh.

Answer (score 1):

To piggy back Jaap's answer:

"sc-" Server-to-client actions

```
sc-substatus - The substatus error code.
sc-win32-status - The Windows status code.
time-taken - The length of time that the action took, in milliseconds.
```

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/676400bc-8969-4aa7-851a-9319490a9bbb.mspx?mfr=true)